# Issues accessing wordpress home page from browser

Tags: wordpress

I installed word press successfully and i have started desiging my website ckcmc.org. I can view page on design mode but when i use browser my page does not display rather I noticed that index.html in public_html folder displays "website under construction" I have renamed the index.html but now it does not display anything. my wp folder in inside the public_html
 Please assist me. I am a beginner in wordpress.

Comment: Hi, you may find better answers at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any cdn like **cloudflare** then login and set mode to **Development Mode** and if not then this must be your browsers cache: there are somethings to do prevent cache: use **CTRL+F5** and use  **incognito window** and http://example.com?nocache=1. and make sure you disabled all **caching plugins** while website is under development.